# Display an Unicode character on JButton

Tags: java, swing, unicode, awt, jbutton

I am writing a code for a calculator. Everything works fine but instead of a square root symbol (√) I am getying a question mark (**?**). Does this mean I can't print Unicode characters on `JButton` or am I wrong?

Here are two pieces containing the required character.

```
String operatorButtonText[] = {"/", "√", "*", "%", "-", "1/X", "+", "=" };

/***************/
if(opText.equals("√"))  
{  
try  
    {double tempd=Math.sqrt(temp);  
    cl.displayLabel.setText(MyCalculator.getFormattedText(tempd));}  
        catch(ArithmeticException excp)  
                {cl.displayLabel.setText("Divide by 0.");}  
return;  
}
```

Here is an image that could be helpful.
I Have marked my problem in red circle.

[image]

Comment: It means the font you are using doesn't have a symbol for that character, try a different font.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch *"try a different font"* Great idea. But there's no need to try fonts at random. See methods of `Font` starting with `canDisplay..` for helpful methods. E.G. [`Font.canDisplay(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplay-int-)

Comment: Here is a [code example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18858313/418556) that uses both `canDisplay(..)` & `canDisplayUpTo(..)`. The latter is used to check that a font can display the name of the font.

Comment: See question [Display an Unicode character on JButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42333787/display-an-unicode-character-on-jbutton)

Comment: I am not using any font types

Comment: Well that's your problem.  The *default* font that you are using doesn't have glyph for the square-root code-point.

Comment: BTW - `catch(ArithmeticException excp)  {cl.displayLabel.setText("Divide by 0.");}` rather than presume, better to.. `..setText(ecxp.getMessage())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
String SQR = "\u221A";
Button b=new Button(SQR);
```

Comment: You should give more context/explanation for the code.

Comment: Don't mix Swing & AWT components without good reason. It is likely this answer fixes the problem (on at least one PC) 'by accident' of the different font used. Given the nature of AWT, that font cannot be relied on in the next PC(/OS).