# Roboto does not display correctly with the Arabic language

Tags: java, swing, fonts, roboto

I have a problem on Roboto font where the Arabic language is not displayed correctly, on the fonts I'm not very prepared but I think it does not support Arabic unicode.

My project deals with a material theme for swing and therefore I would not change fonts for the Arabic language support so I thought that when the theme is loaded I check for a keyboard layaut and if that language is not supported by a robot then change font to loading, this is the only solution I could find but the solution does not work for devices without a keyboard.

Now I would like to ask you two questions:

- Is it possible to find the roboto font that supports Arabic and the languages of that lineage there?
- Is there any better solution than mine if I need to change font for support?

---------- Problem Load Font to GraphicsEnvironment -------
I have rewritten fonts of different types and now through a method written by me I go to set the font according to the style and the support of the String but I get this problem when I go to render the look and feel

```
static {
    try {
        //Noto sans
        Font black = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/fonts/NotoSans/NotoSans-Black.ttf"));
        Font blackItalic = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/fonts/NotoSans/NotoSans-BlackItalic.ttf"));
        Font bold = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/fonts/NotoSans/NotoSans-Bold.ttf"));
        Font boldItalic = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/fonts/NotoSans/NotoSans-BoldItalic.ttf"));
        Font italic = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/fonts/NotoSans/NotoSans-Italic.ttf"));
        Font light = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/fonts/NotoSans/NotoSans-Light.ttf"));
        Font lightItalic = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/fonts/NotoSans/NotoSans-LightItalic.ttf"));
        Font medium = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/fonts/NotoSans/NotoSans-Medium.ttf"));
        Font mediumItalic = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/fonts/NotoSans/NotoSans-MediumItalic.ttf"));
        Font regular = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/fonts/NotoSans/NotoSans-Regular.ttf"));
        Font thin = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/fonts/NotoSans/NotoSans-Thin.ttf"));
        Font thinItalic = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/fonts/NotoSans/NotoSans-ThinItalic.ttf"));
        //Register font
        GraphicsEnvironment graphicsEnvironment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(black);
        graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(blackItalic);
        graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(bold);
        graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(boldItalic);
        graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(italic);
        graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(light);
        graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(lightItalic);
        graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(medium);
        graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(mediumItalic);
        graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(regular);
        graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(thin);
        graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(thinItalic);

        black = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Black.ttf"));
        //blackItalic = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/Roboto/Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf"));
        bold = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf"));
        boldItalic = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf"));
        italic = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Italic.ttf"));
        light = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf"));
        lightItalic = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-LightItalic.ttf"));
        medium = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Medium.ttf"));
        mediumItalic = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf"));
        regular = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf"));
        thin = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Thin.ttf"));
        thinItalic = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf"));

        //register font
        graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(black);
        //graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(blackItalic);
        graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(bold);
        graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(boldItalic);
        graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(italic);
        graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(light);
        graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(lightItalic);
        graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(medium);
        graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(mediumItalic);
        graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(regular);
        graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(thin);
        graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(thinItalic);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FontFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Font getFont(String textCompatibily, String tipeFont){
    String familyFontRoboto = "Roboto";
    String familyFontNotoSans = "Noto Sans";
    GraphicsEnvironment graphicsEnvironment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    //System.out.println(familyFontRoboto + " " + tipeFont);
    for(Font font : graphicsEnvironment.getAllFonts()){
        if(font.canDisplayUpTo(textCompatibily) < 0){
            if(font.getName().equals(familyFontRoboto + " " + tipeFont)){
                System.out.println("Roboto ok");
                System.out.println(font.toString());
                return font;
            }
        }
    }
    for(Font font : graphicsEnvironment.getAllFonts()){
        if(font.canDisplayUpTo(textCompatibily) < 0){
            if(font.getName().equals(familyFontNotoSans + " " + tipeFont)){
                System.out.println("noto sans ok");
                return font;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print("ops");
    return graphicsEnvironment.getAllFonts()[0]; // Noto sans dovrebbe coprire tutto, altrimenti questa cosa si allunga
}
```

setting font on the button

```
Font font = MaterialFonts.getFont(button.getText(), "Black");
    button.setFont (font);
```

problem rendering is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpOmH.png)

Comment: *"Is there any better solution .. if I need to change font ..?"* See [`Font.canDisplayUpTo(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplayUpTo-java.lang.String-). See also [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42335976/418556).

Comment: @AndrewThompson And if I did not know what the font should be applied to ?? my problem concerns a look and feel material for swing and so I have to load the right font to set the font to the declaration of the look and feel

Comment: *"And if I did not know what the font should be applied to ??"* Did you check the second link? It includes a [mcve] that **demonstrates going through all installed fonts** and listing the ones that support a given `String`!

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes I had seen it, I'm sorry I expressed myself badly.

I wanted to say that that method sees the fonts supported by java right ?? if I had in the folder of my project a fot that supports Arabic and I would like to use that I can not search for the character with the right solution?

Comment: *"if I had in the folder of my project a fot that supports Arabic and I would like to use that I can not search for the character with the right solution?"* Sure you can. Just instantiate it first, as seen in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13718134/418556)!

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks now I will see a little to understand how to use it all

Comment: @AndrewThompson Hello I tried the method you suggested but I found the following error, you place the code on the main page, can you give me a hand?

Comment: *"you place the code on the main page"* What reported that error? Your IDE? The SO site? *"can you give me a hand?"* I'm trying, but I won't spoon-feed you (or anyone). Help your self by being more specific and copy/pasting **any** error or exception output. Note that uncompilable code snippet above is not an MCVE. Tip: Get it working with **one** font rather than see it fail with a dozen.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm not looking for the solution, but I look for a point on which to solve the problem, I use two Noto and Roboto fonts, in my function that returns a font I search the font that supports the component text and that has the desired style.
It works, It does what it needs to do only when I go to assign the font to the JButton in this case, the stucco is rendered as photos.           I'm sorry if I'm giving you problems but I'm trying to learn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Roboto' is owned by Google... It doesn't support Arabic ... Google uses a fallback font named 'noto font' where 'roboto' isn't supported...

Comment: So either I change foundations or I find a way to make the change at the moment, right?