# How to show Lao (language) in Swing control?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, localization

When I change to Lao language input in `JTextField`, it displays like this:

[image]

I want to know how to show correct Lao language characters in Swing control, like text field etc.  (By the way - Thai and Chinese display correctly.)

Comment: Use a [compatible font](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42335976/418556)..

Comment: thanks for comments, your link give me direction, but in the link you put , it is very difficult to a new GUI programmer, it is lucky to solve the issue by downloading Lao unicode font "Phetsarath_OT.ttf".

Comment: Good-o. See also how to [load and install a custom `Font`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8365030/418556).

Comment: BTW - congrats on finding the solution to the problem. :) Now there are a couple of different things you might do. 1) (preferred) answer the question, below. If you do that, please let me know. 2) Delete the question. There should be a link among the options below left of the question ('share', 'edit' etc.).

Answer (score 0):

i solved the issue by downloading Lao unicode font "Phetsarath_OT.ttf" , The download link is :
https://www.phetsarath.gov.la/download.php