# Why would a text symbol work on mac but not on windows. ☆

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, fonts

I have a JLabel that gets populated with stars and it only prints successfully on Mac, but when I run it on windows it gives me a bunch of gibberish. Instead of showing the star it looks like a foreign language character instead.

☆ ☆ This is the symbol I am trying to add to the JLabel.☆ ☆

Comment: This is typically and issue with the font

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42335976/418556) shows how to find fonts that will display particular strings of characters.

Comment: @AndrewThompson when I run the character threw the same code posted in that answer it gives "Impact" which is what I am using as a viable font however thats the font I was using and it wasn't working.

Comment: I have Impact font installed. Post a [mre] & I'll try it. Should only take a handful of lines of code.