# Java AWT Graphics2D drawString method does not work with arabic text

Tags: java, fonts, awt

I have a requirement to draw using the method `.drawString` from Graphics2D (`java.awt`) a text in arabic.
But when I use the method using the following code it will just show a bunch of empty squares

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D graphics = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
graphics.drawString("مرحبا هذا نص عربي",
                        xStartText, endY + smallRectHeight);
```

[The resulted output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jszR.png)

Can somebody help? I've search for code snippets to solve this problem but I could not find anything out there?

Comment: try encoding the string with a different standard

Comment: @Berto99 I recently faced this problem too, unfornunately could not solve it yet. But I tried encoding the text in UTF-8 and it did not solve the issue.

Comment: @Triple3XH have you tried using the encoded string instead of the "original" one? for example using https://www.browserling.com/tools/utf8-encode

Comment: maybe try `graphics.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));` or with any font that can display that characters - posted code worked perfectly for me (Java 16, default "Dialog" or "Monospaced" or "Aria" fonts)

Comment: Have you tried using a JFrame to show text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless supplying a font (with the app.) that can support Arabic characters, best to [find a suitable font at run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42335976/418556).

> I supplied Noto Sans Arabic as a font ..

Supplying the font is the most *robust* solution IMO. A couple of tips: See also the accepted answer to [How do you import a font?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8364787/418556) & note the font will become an embedded resource by the time the app. is deployed. The [info page for embedded resources](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) provides tips on how to get a URL pointing to the font.

> .. and it worked as desired.

Glad you got it sorted.